# Drupal 7 from one computer's MAMP to another

Tags: apache, drupal, mamp

I developed a Drupal 7 e-commerce site on my old Mac laptop's MAMP. Unfortunately, during the OS upgrade, something went wrong with apache server and I need to move the site from that laptop to another mac's MAMP (with healthy apache server). Can I just copy the site & database from one doc to another medieval-style? If not - does anybody has any other suggestion?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes, fix your Apache :) – Most important is the database. And code was hopefully committed to a Git repo.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, leymannx. It's been appreciated. Unfortunately, the code wasn't committed to a Gir repo. Would it still be possible to copy/paste from one htdoc to another?

Comment: Just try it out. I'd say yes :)